# Configuring Hudson plug-in in eclipse using HTTPS url and required certificates

Tags: eclipse-plugin, jenkins, hudson

I installed Hudson plugin in my Eclipse by following this [link](https://code.google.com/p/hudson-eclipse/). I got this working in my eclipse for non-ssl Hudson url.

But when I try to configure Hudson in Eclipse (using eclipse-hudson plugin, Windows > Preferences > Hudson > Hudson Base URL) with HTTPS URL below error is thrown:

```
sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: ...Exception: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
```

I am not sure how to configure SSL certificates in Eclipse so that SSL enabled URL can be configured for Hudson.

Any Idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got the solution. I need to generate required certificate to resolve this issue.

1. Download [tool](http://wiki.openkm.com/index.php/File%3aInstallCert.java) to generate certificate and compile java class
2. Run this command **java InstallCert app-server-ip:app-server-port**
3. Copy generated **jssecacerts** file into $JAVA_HOME/lib/security for the JRE that eclipse is using for its runtime

This resolved my problem.